# Need help to Implementing Biometrics test on AWS device-farm

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios, aws-device-farm

I am implementing a solution based upon device farm and appium java (TestNG based). We have some scenarios like biometrics registrations etc. which are working fine on emulators but can't see any support from AWS side.

Can anyone please guide on this.
for Android we use : driver.fingerPrint(1);

and for iOS we use : driver.performTouchID(true);

Any help will be appreciated !!!
Thanks,
Gagan

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Appium methods you are using locally are designed to only work on emulators. As AWS Device Farm only uses real physical devices, these will not work for it. In general, Device Farm supports standard code-based mocking techniques for these sensors. For example, in the debug version of your app, you may include code to specifically say “if I am running on Device Farm, then select a photo from my storage, else select a photo from my hardware camera”. Here are some guides for doing these things for Android and iOS for the camera (with fingerprint and face ID operating similarly):

Android: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38456189/15903511
iOS: http://zacstewart.com/2018/10/09/mocking-the-isight-camera-in-the-ios-simulator.html